# Which versions of the Apple Watch is Pokemon Go compatible with?

Tags: pokemon-go, apple-watch

The update for Pokemon Go that integrates it with the Apple Watch has finally been released.

However, I cannot find any information about whether it is compatible with the first generation watches, or just the newest shiniest models.

Is Pokemon Go compatible with Series 1 Apple watches?

Comment: Nitpick: Series 1 isn't the original Watch — it's that, but with the improved CPU of the Series 2 Watch. Or in other words, it's Series 2 minus the waterproofing, the GPS, and the extra battery capacity that the GPS needs. (The original Watch doesn't have a name that easily differentiates it from the new ones, but some call it "Series 0".) Regardless, GO works on all three (I spent all day running around SF with it on my 2015 watch).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the game is compatible with every series of the Apple Watch. Looking at some commentaries on this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/5jsde6/pokemon_go_is_out_for_the_apple_watch/), it looks like Series 1 users are able to play it too:

> Q : It's only for Apple Watch 2 or the old watch can get it too?
>
> A : All watches I presume. Works on my Series 1

And for original series:

> Q : I'm hearing it is only for Apple Watch series 2 because of the built in gps can anyone confirm?
>
> A : Works on the original Apple Watch. I have the first
>
> A : Can confirm! You can even set the game as a complication on your watch face.

Comment: True. AFAIK, at least as of watchOS 3, there's no way to *make* a watch app require a certain model of Watch. Although I hear the new watches have better battery life, which might come in handy for GO...

Comment: @rickster: Part of my concern was since Series 2 has GPS functionality the previous ones don't, it could have been hooking into that instead of using the phone's. At which point, even if you installed it successfully, you still wouldn't be able to actually use the app.

Comment: Again from the developer POV: as far as a watchOS app is concerned, there's no difference between a S2 and S0/S1 watch. You [use the same APIs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39580515/957768) to get location either way... it's just that on the S2 watch, they magically keep working even when you get too far away from the paired iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Series 4 won't allow the Pokémon Go app to appear as a complication on the face of the watch. No response from Niantic on this. I guess Apple watch owners are a very low priority to Niantic, even though this is the number one watch that is being sold today.